# feedit for non admin users is not working in TYPO3 4.5.26

Tags: typo3

I am having a site with typo3 4.5.26 and I have installed the advancedfeedit extension.
Fe edit works fine for admin users but for non admins it wont show any options though i have set ts properly

Here my ts setup :

```
admPanel{
  enable.edit=1  
  hide=1
}
```

Anything extra i need to do ?
Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

I think *hide* should be *0*

```
admPanel {
  enable.edit = 1
  hide = 0
}
```